# Merge rows by adding the deviating value as new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to output for each person that has filled out a specific questionnaire their personal data as well as the data from the specific questionnaire/assessment. The values are stored in the table criteriaDF.

The result of my current query:

| KlientId | Name1 | Name2 | CriteriaName | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 335 | Name1Person1 | Name2Person1 | IF1 | Yes |
| 335 | Name1Person1 | Name2Person1 | IF2 | Yes |
| 335 | Name1Person1 | Name2Person1 | IF3 | No |
| 336 | Name1Person2 | Name2Person2 | IF1 | Yes |
| 336 | Name1Person2 | Name2Person2 | IF2 | Yes |
| 336 | Name1Person2 | Name2Person2 | IF3 | No |

What I want to have:

| KlientId | Name1 | Name2 | IF1 | IF2 | IF3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 335 | Person1Name1 | Person1Name2 | Yes | Yes | No |
| 336 | Person2Name1 | Person2Name2 | Yes | No | No |

So the criterias should get their own columns and the rows referencing the same person should merge into one based on the same KlientId.
The query I used to get my current result uses a few joins in order to get from person to client, to process to assessment to criteria, where the CriteriaName and Result lies. The other tables are just used with their foreign keys to get to these values "IF1: Yes" etc.

```
SELECT Client.Id, Person.Name1, Person.Name2, Person.Birthday, CriteriaDF.CriteriaName, CriteriaDF.Result
FROM Client
INNER JOIN Person ON Client.PersonId=Person.Id
INNER JOIN Process ON Client.Id=Process.ClientId
INNER JOIN AssessmentDF ON Process.Id=AssessmentDF.ProCessId
INNER JOIN CriteriaDF ON AssessmentDF.Id=CriteriaDF.AssessmentDfId
WHERE AssessmentDF.Name='RightAssessmentName' AND AssessmentDF.Date > DATEADD(day, -180, GETDATE())
```

Edit: Query using aliases:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.Name1, t2.Name2, t2.Birthday, t5.CriteriaName, t5.Result
FROM Client AS t1
INNER JOIN Person AS t2 ON t1.PersonId=t2.Id
INNER JOIN Process AS t3 ON t1.Id=t3.ClientId
INNER JOIN AssessmentDF AS t4 ON t3.Id=t4.ProcessId
INNER JOIN CriteriaDF AS t5 ON t4.Id=t5.AssessmentDfId
WHERE t4.Bezeichnung='RightAssessmentName' AND t4.Date > DATEADD(day, -180, GETDATE())
```

My main question is how to convert the tuples CriteriaName & Result to a new column for each unique CriteriaName and Fill the cell with the Result.

I dont think they're important, but here are all minimal tables that are used to get from the person to the criterias (Ids might not fit perfectly to the result & what I wanted to have, just to understand how the data is stored):

Table Person:

| Id | Name1 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2766 | Person1Name1 | Person1Name2 |
| 2767 | Person2Name2 | Person2Name2 |
| 2768 | Person3Name2 | Person3Name2 |

Table Klient:

| Id | PersonId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2766 |
| 335 | 2767 |
| 336 | 2768 |

Table Process:

| Id | KlientId |
| --- | --- |
| 2485 | 335 |
| 2515 | 336 |
| 2519 | 336 |

Table AssessmentDF

| Id | ProcessId | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | 2485 | 2022-04-18 | RightAssessmentName |
| 44 | 2515 | 2022-05-18 | RightAssessmentName |
| 45 | 2519 | 2022-06-18 | RightAssessmentName |

Table CriteriaDF:
In reality there is IF1-If19

| Id | AssessmentDfId | CriteriaName | ProcessId | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 551 | 43 | IF1 | 2485 | Yes |
| 552 | 43 | IF2 | 2485 | Yes |
| 553 | 43 | IF3 | 2485 | No |
| 554 | 44 | IF1 | 2515 | Yes |
| 555 | 44 | IF2 | 2515 | Yes |
| 556 | 44 | IF3 | 2515 | No |
| 557 | 45 | IF1 | 2519 | Yes |
| 558 | 45 | IF2 | 2519 | No |
| 559 | 45 | IF3 | 2519 | No |

Comment: I highly recommend short table aliases as a way to make your query more readable.

Comment: "I dont think they're important" - really? They are critical to understanding the problem - please continue to add that level of detail.

Comment: Sure they are important. I meant that their only purpose if to use their foreign keys to get deeper to the table CriteriaDF, where CriteriaName and Results are stored. The data 
I want for my query output is only in the tables Person and CriteriaDF - but you're right, the others tables might also be important for a different approach. As far as I can see I've added everything that is needed, there is no more useful information in the different tables. As far as the aliases are concernced, I will make sure to include them in the future.  I believe for the little snippet query above it is okay.